# Plotting scatterplots with pairs in R, in log scale with data containing zeros

Tags: r, dataframe, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot some pairs of scatterplots using "pairs".
My dataframe look like :

```
    >e
    X Y Z
    0 0 0
    2 3 4
    0 3 4
    3 3 3
```

A completely standard dataframe here.

I use this to plot my scatter plots, again nothing fancy:

```
pairs(~X+Y+Z, data=e, log="xy")
```

It works great, but it doesn't plot the labels. However if I remove the log="xy" in the command, then the labels are plotted nicely. So I guess it has to do with the fact that I want my scatterplots to be in log scale.

So my question is what shall I do? 
Shall I remove all lines with zeros in it before hand (how do you do that?)
Is there a magic trick that will let me have log="xy" and my scatterplots labeled?

Please let me know if it is not clear.

Answer (score 7):

You ignored this (where I called your data frame `DF`):

```
R> pairs(~X+Y+Z, data=df, log="xy")
There were 30 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

and if you look at these thirty warnings, you will see that

- you cannot plot data containing zeros on a log scale (and I guess you know why)
- `log` is not a recognised parameter for `pairs()`

So if you want a pairs plot in logs, you may have to takes logs yourself (and either add a small epsilon or use a transformation like `log(1 + x)` and call `pairs()` on that data.

*Edit*  The easiest is probably    `pairs(~X+Y+Z, data=log(1+DF))`

Comment: This is strange behavior though.  It actually *does* plot the data on a log scale, everything looks fine, except it omits the labels.  A similar outcome happens with `plot(df, log="xy")`, where `log` is (presumably?) a valid parameter for `plot()`.

Comment: Also, not to nitpick because your solution is the best I know, but `pairs(~X+Y+Z, data=log(1+DF))` will alter the axis labels undesirably to the logged-scale.