# Setting log scale within pairs()

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to set some of axis to appropriate log scales and some should remain
'normal'. Has anybody done that so far? Also the labels should then be 10^1,10^2 etc. 
It is not an option to log-transform the data before because then I don't get the labels I want. A similar topic was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748636/plotting-scatterplots-with-pairs-in-r-in-log-scale-with-data-containing-zeros/9890323#comment12616019_9890323), but in my case I don't need/want to transform log(x+1) beforehand.

Is there any way to do that (setting log-axis) directly with pairs? Maybe tweaking the code?... Your help is much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to the plot function used in pairs. E.g.:

```
Dat <- matrix(exp(rnorm(100,0,2) + rnorm(300)),100,3)
pairs(Dat,log="xy")
```

Gives you a bunch of warnings but also seem to work in that you do get log scales.

Comment: yes with the log-argument I get log scales, but for all variables. As I said before I want to set some of axis to log scales and some should remain 'normal'.

Answer (score 0):

Using `?pairs`, I find the following:

"log = a character string indicating if logarithmic axes are to be used, see plot.default or a **numeric vector of indices specifying the indices of those variables where logarithmic axes should be used** for both x and y. log = "xy" specifies logarithmic axes for all variables."

`pairs(my_data_frame, log = 3)`

will use log scale for the variable in column 3, the remaining variables plotted using linear scale.  The test cases I tried worked...